# Flutter setting a value of TextFormField according to setState of a widget variable

Tags: flutter, widget

how can i set the value of a `TextFormField` from a widget variable when this variable changed according to a `setstate` action after building the widget and not by the initial value of this `textformfeild`

 what i know that i can change its value by using the `TextEditingController` but i have too many `TextFormField` and creating the `TextEditingController` take a lot of code by using the traditional way by adding them the whole widget:
1-Create a TextEditingController.
2-Connect the TextEditingController to a text field.
3-Create a function to update the latest value.
4-Listen to the controller for changes.
is there any way to build this controller and do those steps inside the code of the `TextFormField` only? or another way ?

Comment: I assume you want a very simple way  to put text into your textfield everytime you called setState?

Comment: yes like this what i need

Answer (score 4):

place controler in

```
TextFormField(
      controller: TextEditingController(text: daytask),....
```

then place `setstate() txt='';` like this

```
setState(() { txt='' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is to simply make a widget. For this one, here is the code that i would use

```
class StateTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const StateTextField({Key key, this.text = ''}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: TextEditingController(text: text),
    );
  }
}
```

that should do the work. If u want to pass the controller,  u can pass it too. And to use it, just call the class in build method.

Answer (score 1):

Similar example with `TextFormField`, `TextEditingController`, clickable `suffixIcon` for a `selectDate` `showDatePicker` (this is a standard material "lambda" dialog) where `setState` is updating the initial set date (not by the `initialValue`, rather by the `controller` parameter) with a new date.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateOrderForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateOrderForm({Key? key}):super(key: key);

  @override
  CreateOrderFormState createState() => CreateOrderFormState();
}

class CreateOrderFormState extends State<CreateOrderForm>
{
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late DateTime selectedDate;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    print("initState selectedDate = ${selectedDate.toLocal()}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print("build prepare selectedDate: ${selectedDate.toLocal()}");

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [             
              TextFormField(
                //initialValue: "${selectedDate.toLocal()}",
                controller: TextEditingController(text: "${selectedDate.toLocal()}"),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.event),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: "Assignment Date & Time",
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.event))
                ),
              ),             
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8)),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: ((){}),
                  child: Text("Submit")),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  _selectDate(BuildContext context) async{
    await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1970),
        lastDate: DateTime(9999)
    ).then((value){
      if(value != null && value != selectedDate)
      {
        this.setState(() {
          selectedDate = value;
          print("New date ${selectedDate.toLocal()}");
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
TextField(                           
  controller: TextEditingController(text: '10'),                          
  style: TextStyle(
  fontSize: 20,                          
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextField(
  controller: TextEditingController()..text = 'Your initial value',
  onChanged: (text) => {},
)
```